# Can a lipo battery be charged with more than 0.5 amps?

Tags: lipo-batteries, battery-safety, charging

Using ISDT q8 to charge my 1205mAh 6S lipo battery. I'm wondering if I can change the default settings and charge with more amps?

Is this recommended or will it degrade the battery much quicker. Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey DroneDome, might this question have the answer to your question? https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/971/97

Comment: Thank @ifconfig, thats question answers my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely can charge your 1205 mAh 6S LiPo at a current higher than 0.5A. For most of the LiPos we use on drones, the recommended charge rate is 1C, which for your battery, would be about **1.2Amps**. (A 1C charge rate is 1 Amp for every 1000mAh)

A 1C charge rate is a good middle ground, but you can use a lower charge rate (~0.5C) for safer but slower charging, or a higher charge rate (~2C) for faster charging at the expense of the battery's longevity (and more risk of fire).

And as @ifconfig mentioned, this [similar question](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/971/at-what-current-should-i-charge-a-lipo-battery) should also help answer your question.